# DataGridView аля «Система компоновки данных - 1С:Предприятие»

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Задача: есть `DataGridView`, в который выводится разная нужная информация. Cо временем информации, которую хотят видеть, много прирастает.

- При этом всяко картинки подсветки и т.п. присутствуют. При этом одни пользователи хотят видеть одно, другим надо видеть другое, и так по нарастающей...

Давно им обещал сделать со временем "кастомизацию" данной таблички, точнее самим им дать возможность в **своих настройках** решать **самим**, какую информацию они хотят видеть всегда (сразу при запуске), иметь возможность по необходимости добавить / убрать какое-то поле и т.п.

В общем хочется что-то типа [Система компоновки данных - 1С:Предприятие 8](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000093.htm): нажали кнопочку — выбрали что хотят видеть, всё это сохранилось где-нибудь в настройках пользователя, и при построении этого Grid уже всё строилось так, как хочется пользователю.

Обещать — наобещал, но куда копать пока понять не могу. Кто подскажет, куда подсмотреть (без затрат на покупку стороннего, можно скачать)? Может идеи есть и т.п.?

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: для работы с БД MSSQL работаю посредством LINQtoSQL, в проект подгружен DBML файл со структурой и через DataContext запрашиваю нужные мне данные...

Comment: ну и всяко-разная информация - это информация не из одной таблицы, а из связанных, в том числе и из связанных со связанными... в принципе строк обычно не более 300 выходит в таблице... для понимания... выводятся сведения по автомобилям в наличии (б/у) и к ним в добавку сведения из таблицы с информацией о его поступлении, а так же из связанных поступлением шин с/без дисков (в виде картинки), сведения об обращениях клиентов по этим атомобилям и т.д. и т.п. т.е. сквозной информации море...

Comment: вот и хочется одним видеть одно, другим другое... но выводить эту информацию разом и предлагать пользователю настраивать видимость и очередность столбцов повесится можно...